# How to use OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, oauth-2.0

I know basic of HTML, Javascript and PHP. I need to use API authorization of another server in my web application. I have read the documentation of that server but I was not able to figure it out how to start. Then I started to search famous servers such as Google and I realize the documentation is very similar but still I am not sure to where copy and paste the code. There is couple of example URLs. Should I copy paste them inside my code? I will appreciate if anyone knows where to start.
The steps are very similar which I saw in google documentation. Here:

```
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GettingStarted with OAuth**
There is a course on KnpUniversity that gives you a good overview over oath-implementation in PHP: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/oauth
You can watch the first two videos for free, after that you can still read the transcription and view the code examples.

**Deep dive**
If you want to deep dive into OAuth read the official OAuth 2 specification at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749. It takes a while and it might be helpful to grab a pen and paper to sketch some flows, but it's quite easy to read.

## Protocol Endpoints

To address your question:
A OAuth-Authorization-Server have to has two endpoint: the Authorization Endpoint and the Token Endpoint. Where they are located is not specified!

Google's endpoints are:

- Authorization: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
- Token: https://accounts.google.com//o/oauth2/token

facebook's endpoints are:

- Authorization: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
- Token: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token

So you have to find out the URLs to these two endpoints at the authorization server you wan't to use.

## Authorizations Grants

The official specification specifies four different ways to obtain authorization at the authorization endpoint called grants.
These are:

- Authorization Code Grant
- Implicit Grant
- Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant
- Client Credentials Grant
  Furthermore it is allowed to specify own grant types so have a look for that in the documentation of the endpoint.

The *most common* grant type is the Authorization Code Grant. I highly recommend to have a look to the specification for understanding grant types: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4. The figures contained are really helpful!
The specification also contains a example for each grant type that explains how to get an access token.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is an open standard for authenticating users and providing access token to retrieve their data. For implementing google oauth and api's you should first create a project and id's in google console. Then implement it in your application. A good tutorial of Google OAuth 2.0 with source code is given at [Implementing Google OAuth 2.0](http://www.yogihosting.com/blog/implementing-google-contacts-api-version-3-0-oauth-2-0-in-csharp-and-asp-net/)

It is also important that you should know how to do Rest Calls to google.